# Counting a phrase in a cell with other content

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to count a few variables in a single column of cells as shown in the picture. Using =Countif is interrupted by other content in a cell. (I know I could count them in multiple cells it would just be far cleaner to keep them in one column)

[The highlighted result is counting 2 "R"s though I need it to count all three](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIFVu.png)

If there's a way to use functions or conditional formatting rules to achieve this I'd be grateful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `=SUM()` over a new column containing this formula: `=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"R",""))`, which assumes column A contains your original data.

This trick uses the length of your original string versus the length of the string after you've substituted the magic string(s) you are searching for with empty strings -- effectively eliminating the magic string(s) from your original string.  The difference in string lengths reveals how many instances of your magic string(s) appeared in the original string.

Comment: This helped a lot, thank you.